# Complex numbers: Orders of powers and multiplication

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the following complex number multiplication:

$$\overline{(iz)^2}$$

With $z = 2e^\frac{\pi}{3}$

The answer is $4e^\frac{\pi}{3}$; but I keep getting $4e^\frac{-5\pi}{3}$

What I did is: I wrote down $i$ in exponential form as $1e^\frac{\pi}{2}$. Then I multiply $z$ and $i$ (both in polar form) which gets me $2e^\frac{5\pi}{6}$. I then apply the power of 2, which gets me $4e^\frac{5\pi}{3}$ and then I "apply" the conjugate which gives me $4e^\frac{-5\pi}{3}$.

Where's my mistake? Has it got to do with the order of multiplication/division?

Comment: The answers are effectively equivalent. Note that in polar form you could have an angle be the same, up to a multiple of $2\pi$.

Comment: $\,\pi/3 - (- 5 \pi/3) = \dots\,$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The period of $\sin$ and $\cos$ is $2\pi$ meaning values generated by $sin$ and $cos$ separated by this distance are the same and with $\pi /3 - (-5\pi /3) = 2\pi$ they are equivalent.

Comment: The thing is however, $-5\pi/3$ is not considered correct. Is it because of a consensus?

Comment: Im unsure what you mean because the two complex numbers are equal to one another, is a teacher just saying they would prefer a positive power, but if you think about it as the argument of the complex number you can see they are the same, try converting them into $x+yi$ form and you will see that they are the same.

Comment: Hey there jack, you were right. My professor said that it is preferred if the angle is larger than 0 but smaller than 2 \pi.
Thanks for your answer